# How to pass the value to current active form

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

I have main form name as form1 and popup form name as form2

Form1

`tab button` - for creating mulitple copy of form1 at runtime...

Creation of mulitple from1 at runtime code

form1 code

```
Dim mEntryForm As form1
        mEntryForm = New form1
        mEntryForm.Show()
```

The above code is creating a same copy of form1 at runtime.

Now i want to pass the value from popup form to current activeform

Code for sending the value to form1 from popup form (form2)

form2code

```
form1.textbox1.text = "100"
```

The above code is going to `form1 textbox`, instead of active form (`mentryform`)

How to solve this problem.

Need Vb.net code help

Comment: This makes no sence. Why would you want to have multiple mainforms? Then try to control them all with a popup window. To me it sounds like the popup should be main and then you should have the Form1's as popups. This way you can keep track of all Form1 in an array, plus keep track of the currently active "main form". Either this or a build up with a proper main form, multiple form1 and a popup. Which makes everything much more usable...

Comment: Using the *type name* to reference a form is a pretty bad VB.NET practice.  Makes it really hard to ever learn object-oriented programming.  And blows up badly here of course.  You'll need mEntryForm.TextBox1.Text.  Which one of the many instances you want is unguessable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I totaly agree with the comments about your question I ll try to give you a solution

Add a property to your Form2
name smtng like ActiveForm1 as form1

now because I haven't understand completey your concept:

-> if Form2 is a ShowDialog form then you cannot change the active form1. 
   You need to set the property ActiveForm1

```
 dim frm2 as new form2
 frm2.ActiveForm1=me
 frm2.ShowDialog
```

->if Form2 is not a ShowDialog that means that you can change the active form1
then you need to add this lines of code when a form1 is activated

```
frm2.ActiveForm1=me
```

Now in form2:

```
 me.ActiveForm1.textbox1.text = "100"
```

I hope that I helped you.